# How do i insert a Box which i drew out from pen to a picturebox image?

Tags: c#

i need help on inserting a box which i drew out from  into a picturebox.
here is the code of the pen that i code out, i do not know how to put it in the picturebox.
there will be a webcam running on the background of the picturebox, i want my rectangle to be inside the picturebox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button1.Text == "Start")
    {
        Graphics myGraphics = base.CreateGraphics();
        myGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.DarkBlue);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(480, 70, 120, 120);
        myGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, rect);
        stopWebcam = false;
        button1.Text = "Stop";
    }
    else
    {
        stopWebcam = true;
        button1.Text = "Start";
    }
}
```

Comment: To put your rectangle into the picture box create your graphics from the picture box i.e. PictureBox.CreateGraphics(). you will need to figure out some way to combine the two images. The one from your web cam and the rectangle

Comment: Except that you shouldn't do what Mark suggested and instead should perform all of your drawing in OnPaint.  Don't call `CreateGraphics` unless you need to and know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Paining in winforms is primarily done in the OnPaint event. Your ButtonClick event handler should only setup the stage for OnPaint and possibly activate it. Example:

```
public class MyForm : Form
    ...
    private Rectangle? _boxRectangle;   

    private void OnMyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text == "Start")
        {
            _boxRectangle = new Rectangle(...);
            button1.Text = "Stop";
        }
        else
        {
            _boxRectangle = null;
            button1.Text = "Start";
        }
        Invalidate(); // repaint
    }

    protected override OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_boxRectangle != null)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics.
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkBlue);
            g.DrawRectangle(_boxRectangle);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to draw the web cam image onto a bitmap buffer and use that as an image for the picture box.

Here is the msdn page with examples at the bottom:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx

Here is my method for doing it.

```
public void GraphicsToPictureBox (ref PictureBox pb, Graphics graphics,
                              Int32 width, Int32 height) 
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width,height,graphics);
    pb.Image = bitmap;
}
```